# Wildcards in ALB listener rules

Tags: aws-application-load-balancer

I'm trying to add rules to my listener in an ALB. The host headers are of the form:

```
example-1.com
example-2.com
example-3.com
```

Can we use a wildcard for this kind of host header, like this:

```
example-*.com
```

Are wildcard characters (*, ?) allowed in the middle of the url or path?

Answer (score 2):

From this blog post from 2017, it appears that you can.

> You can create Application Load Balancer rule that routes incoming traffic based on the domain name specified in the Host header

> Rules that match the Host header can include up to three “*” (match 0 or more characters) or “?” (match 1 character) wildcards.

[Reference](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-host-based-routing-support-for-aws-application-load-balancers/)